# Pyramid Project: "ValueError: Variable assignment..." when trying to pserve

Tags: python, pyramid

I get the following error when trying to run a Pyramid project. As far as I'm aware, this appeared overnight, and I've no idea how to begin to debug this:

```
C:\mas\mas>..\Scripts\pserve.exe serve development.ini --reload
Starting subprocess with file monitor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mas\Scripts\pserve-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.3.2', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "C:\mas\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.
py", line 47, in main
    return command.run()
  File "C:\mas\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.
py", line 221, in run
    vars = self.parse_vars(restvars)
  File "C:\mas\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.
py", line 330, in parse_vars
    % arg)
ValueError: Variable assignment 'development.ini' invalid (no "=")
```

What is the problem, or how a should I go about determining it? Sorry my question is rather vague, but if I had any more an idea of what I was asking I may have found the answer on Google :).

**Line 328 - 330:**

```
        raise ValueError(
            'Variable assignment %r invalid (no "=")'
            % arg)
```

**development.ini**

```
[app:main]
use = egg:mas

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar
    pyramid_tm
    pyramid_beaker

sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/mas.db

# Cache settings
cache.regions = default_term, second, short_term, long_term
cache.type = memory
cache.second.expire = 1
cache.short_term.expire = 60
cache.default_term.expire = 300
cache.long_term.expire = 3600

# Beaker sessions
#session.type = file
#session.data_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/data
#session.lock_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/lock
session.type = memory
session.key = akhet_demo
session.secret = 0cb243f53ad865a0f70099c0414ffe9cfcfe03ac

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

# Begin logging configuration

[loggers]
keys = root, mas, sqlalchemy

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_mas]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = mas

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine
# "level = INFO" logs SQL queries.
# "level = DEBUG" logs SQL queries and results.
# "level = WARN" logs neither.  (Recommended for production systems.)

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s

# End logging configuration
```

Comment: Can you show us line 330 in `C:\mas\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py`, or the whole function containing that line?

Comment: Okay, hold on I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have the order of the arguments backwards - it should be:

```
..\Scripts\pserve.exe development.ini --reload
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, I've posted the contents of development.ini, I can't see any errors in there.

Comment: @LiamM - I was wrong - the error is telling you that your *command* is wrong, not your INI file.

Comment: *Chuckles* @LiamM Awesome - glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 3):

Ich, I'e worked it out, I was looking for the problem in the wrong place. the problem is this command:

```
..\Scripts\pserve.exe serve development.ini --reload
```

Should be this command:

```
..\Scripts\pserve.exe development.ini --reload
```

I have no idea how or when my batch file got changed, but if someone has a similar problem hopefully this will help.