# Error while starting Pyramid project in Pycharm

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a pyramid project which was fine in another system. I have moved the project to a system where I am using anaconda-python. Apart from that, all other libraries and packages that are required are present. The pyramid project fails to start with the following error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_load_entry_point.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point(dist, "console_scripts", name)()
  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 58, in main
    return command.run()
  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 257, in run
    vars = self.get_options()
  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 197, in get_options
    return parse_vars(restvars)
  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\common.py", line 15, in parse_vars
    % arg)
ValueError: Variable assignment '\\Pyramid1\\development.ini' invalid (no "=")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

development.ini file:

```
###
# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/environment.html
###

[app:main]
use = egg:Pyramid1

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_debugtoolbar
    pyramid_tm
    pyramid_chameleon
# mysql+mysqldb://<user>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+mysqldb://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/db1
sqlalchemy2.url = mysql+mysqldb://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/db2
# By default, the toolbar only appears for clients from IP addresses
# '127.0.0.1' and '::1'.
# debugtoolbar.hosts = 127.0.0.1 ::1

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, sqlalchemy

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_pyramid1]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = pyramid1

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine
# "level = INFO" logs SQL queries.
# "level = DEBUG" logs SQL queries and results.
# "level = WARN" logs neither.  (Recommended for production systems.)

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

I am using python 27 in anaconda. and pycharm 4.5.4

Answer (score 0):

You have pyramid.includes defined twice in a single section:

Try:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:Pyramid1

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar
    pyramid_tm
    pyramid_chameleon
...
```

Comment: Can you post your updated development.ini file. Ill test it locally

Comment: I have Edited the development.ini in the question with changes

Comment: Parses fine on my side, Did the line number from the error change?

Comment: Very strange that definitely fixed the error on my side. Are you 100% sure the correct file was updated?

Comment: I changed my development.ini sample file slightly as well, putting pyramid_debugtoolbar on the same line. Please try that as well

Comment: Tried that as well. and looked up the configuration of the project and of pycharm.

Comment: Which version of pycharm and python?

Comment: According to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515273/pyramid-project-valueerror-variable-assignment-when-trying-to-pserve (possible dupe?) whatever way you're starting Pyramid is either backwards or incorrect. How are you starting it?

Answer (score 0):

The way to diagnose such problems is to open the source file where the error is raised (`C:\Users\abc\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyramid\scripts\common.py`) and add some logging. According to [Pyramid git repo](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/scripts/common.py) the function in question is `parse_vars`. Doing something like this would provide instant insights:

```
def parse_vars(args):
    """
    Given variables like ``['a=b', 'c=d']`` turns it into ``{'a':
    'b', 'c': 'd'}``
    """
    print("parse_vars called with:", args)
    result = {}
    for arg in args:
        print("parsing:", arg)
        if '=' not in arg:
            print("Not happy with %s, going to raise an exception" % arg)
            raise ValueError(
                'Variable assignment %r invalid (no "=")'
                % arg)
        name, value = arg.split('=', 1)
        result[name] = value
    return result
```

Wonders of a scripting language, you can even poke into Python's standard library functions :) Just don't forget to change it back when you're done.

Now, looking at your traceback it becomes obvious that the function gets the wrong input - instead of a string in format `'a=b'` it gets `'\\Pyramid1\\development.ini'`. If you look into [pserve.py](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py) you'll see that's it's more related to parsing command line arguments passed to the script - your app hasn't even loaded your .ini file yet.